# ElasticSearch : Pagination using query-string-syntax

Tags: elasticsearch

I was going through [Elastic Search query-string-syntax](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).

How can I do pagination using these syntax. Like 10 record per page.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
curl -XPOST "http://HOSTNAME:9200/Index/Type/_search?q=title:(quick brown)&size=10&from=0"

curl -XPOST "http://HOSTNAME:9200/Index/Type/_search?q=title:(quick brown)&size=1&from=20"

curl -XPOST "http://HOSTNAME:9200/Index/Type/_search?q=title:(quick brown)&size=10&from=30"
```

Increase from value to get next 10 documents..

HOpe it helps..!